# HTACCESS Rewriting an external server image path that is added to my website

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a two servers connected to one website written in php,one server is to get the data from the database and the images are stored in another server. I wish to hide the path of the image server using htaccess, Right now my Img Src will be like

i'm at domain1.com,Images are at domain2.com,

```
My domain1.com code will be like, 
<img src='https://domain2.com/uploads/imagefolder/image.jpg' />

I want it like 
<img src='/uploads/imagefolder/image.jpg' />
```

Do you have a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could do this by getting the server with the database to serve the images from the second server (i.e. it reads the image and sends the data to the client).  This will of course increase the network traffic and add delays, but not sure of any other way.

Comment: Thank you for the reply , right now it is not possible to do that way , because i hardcoded the path in some mobile apps ( More than 30 customers using it ) , the mobile app caches the images , so it wont require the server to load for the second time , i need to implement the same for the website , browser caching.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no /uploads/imagefolder on server 1 this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(uploads/imagefolder/.*)$ http://example2.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: But not working , i'm using codeigniter framework m i added the line 

RewriteRule ^(uploads/imagefolder/.*)$ http://example2.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

But not working ..